# can't remove file with carriage returns

Tags: shell, command-line, filenames, newlines

I have a file `blahblah\r\n.txt` that I want to remove but `rm blahblah\r\n.txt` does not work as I receive `No such file or directory` message.

How to remove??

Comment: Did you try `rm blabla*.txt`? You also might benefit from tab completion using `rm blahbla`+tab. Third option, if the `\r\n` is listed literally you can use single quotes: `rm 'blabla\r\n'.txt'

Comment: Yes, same result.

Answer (score 3):

You can enclose a string in `$''` to enable the interpretation of escape sequences in it (in this case to enable the interpretation of `\r`):

```
rm $'file\rwith_carriage_return'
```

```
% touch $'file\rwith_carriage_return'
% ls
file?with_carriage_return
% rm $'file\rwith_carriage_return'
% ls
%
```

Comment: I believe this is the best solution, I will accept the answer when I run into the problem again because at the moment I cannot reproduce.

Comment: @zee You can create a test case running `touch $'file\rwith_carriage_return'`, and check that it actually contains it running `ls $'file\rwith_carriage_return' | hexdump -c`

Answer (score 1):

Of the several various methods available, one is to find the inode number and then nuke that.

```
$ mkdir -p ~/tmp/asdf
$ cd !$
cd ~/tmp/asdf
$ touch `head -c 32 /dev/random` # newlines are boring
$ find . -type f -ls
5636303    0 -rw-r--r--   ...
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -inum 5636303 -exec rm '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to delete the file if you escape the filename:
`rm 'bla\n.txt'`

But if that doesn't work try deleting by inode number:

```
ls -i bla*
1234 bla\n.txt
find . -inum 1234
#make sure the right file and only the right file is returned then
find . -inum 1234 -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I run into such situations, I do the following..

EX: Suppose I have the file 'xxx\nyyy'

I know that it starts with 'xxx'.....

I use the command:

```
 rm -i xxx*
```

And delete the RIGHT file when prompted if you want to delete a file or not.

Answer (score 0):

I removed with `rm *.*` however I'd still like to know why `rm blahblah\r\n.txt` and `rm blahblah*.txt` do not work..

Comment: It doesn't work because the shell interprets the backslash to escape the next character. And it seems a literal backslash is needed here.

Comment: Try to echo your command to see how the shell interprets it. `echo rm blahblah\r\n.txt` prints "rm blahblahrn.txt", which can't work as your file is not named blahblahrn.txt